# ssh: tunnel automatically when needed

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I need to ssh to various machines both from work and from home.  When at work, I can use my `~/.ssh/config` host definitions easily, and just do:

```
ssh servername_shortcut
```

When I'm at home, I need to tunnel through a gateway server, which is a multi-step & tedious process

```
ssh -N -f -C -L 2024:servername:22 username@gateway.hostname.org
ssh -p 2024 username@localhost
```

(this is particularly annoying because I have to manually kill the tunnel when I disconnect)

Similarly, I often need to rsync things, which requires:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 2024' username@localhost:...
```

instead of

```
rsync username@servername_shortcut
```

Since I'm frequently switching between these situations, I'd really like to be able to use the short version all the time.  Is there any mechanism for achieving this?

EDIT: Specifically, using `~/.ssh/config`, is there a way to specify a hostname that will use `host.domain.org` when allowed, and `localhost:$portnumber` when a tunnel is open?  In pseudocode, I'm asking for this:

```
host myhost
user aginsbur
if tunnel:
    HostName localhost
    port 2022
else:
    HostName myhost.domain.org
```

Comment: Can you not just put the commands into bash scripts?

Comment: You can simply define the `ProxyCommands` in your config to achieve this.

Comment: @jonno yes, for ssh, I can put the commands into bash scripts.  My goal, though, is to use the same commands, or nearly the same commands, independent of my working location, and for rsync that's much more difficult because multiple paths have to be configured.

Answer (score 0):

I know @Jonno already put this in the comments, but it's a great suggestion, and it's exactly what I'd do, so I thought I'd put it here: just put the commands in bash scripts.  E.g.:

```
echo 'ssh -N -f -C -L 2024:servername:22 username@gateway.hostname.org' > ssh_gateway_hostname.sh
```

This'll put the command in a `.sh` file, and then you can run it a couple of different ways:

```
bash ssh_gateway_hostname.sh
```

or

```
source ssh_gateway_hostname.sh
```

While there is a slight difference between the two, it's not likely it'll affect you unless you're doing some fancy stuff with your environments.

The lovely thing about `rsync` is that, after your initial `rsync`ing of a file or directory, successive uses of it only update the changes.  This means that you can simply specify a directory that you want to to synchronize and put that in the `.sh` script:

```
echo 'rsync -e 'ssh -p 2024' username@localhost:...' > rsync_username_at_localhost.sh
```

Then when you run it, it'll only move the new stuff!

Comment: This will force me to always tunnel, which I don't want to do.  Similarly, I am not always connecting to the same host or through the same gateway. I'm not just asking how to repeat bash commands (which is trivial), I'm asking if it is possible to use the same ssh command to perform different operations depending on location